# SQL, multiple rows to one column

Tags: sql, pivot, rows, multiple-columns

So I have the following date

```
ID       NAME       MONTH              COUNT

1        David      December2012       500

2        Rob        December2012       320

1        David      January2013        400

2        Rob        January2013        280
```

I am trying to make this.......

```
ID       Name       December2012       January2013

1        David      500                400

2        Rob        320                280
```

Where I get confused is how I want to keep two of the columns and just pivot the two other fields. Anyone know how I would do this.

Thank you so much for your help/time. I have never posted one of these, and responses are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  NAME,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'December2012' THEN "COUNT" END) AS "December2012",
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'January2013'  THEN "COUNT" END) AS "January2013"
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY ID, Name;
```

Answer (score 5):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using.  You can *pivot* the data in all databases using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select id, name, 
  sum(case when month = 'December2012' then "count" end) December2012,
  sum(case when month = 'January2013' then "count" end) January2013
from yourtable
group by id, name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab152/3)

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ or Oracle 11g then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, name, month, [count]
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum([count])
  for month in (December2012, January2013)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab152/1).

In SQL Server, if the values of the `month` are unknown then you can use dynamic SQL similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select id, name, month, [count]
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum([count])
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab152/4)

All versions yield the result:

```
| ID |  NAME | DECEMBER2012 | JANUARY2013 |
-------------------------------------------
|  1 | David |          500 |         400 |
|  2 |   Rob |          320 |         280 |
```

Comment: This Worked! Thanks so much. At first, I wasn;t sure why you were including the SUM since I wasn;t adding anything with one row per month per person. But then I noticed I had nulls when I took it out and multiple records cause they had to be included in the groupby. I have one more question on this that I am trying to accomplish. I will post a different thread for that but wanted to hank you. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I am very new to this, learning as I go. Thanks!

Comment: @user2051103 typically when you get multiple answers to your question, the normal response is to accept the answer posted first. In this case, my answer was posted first.

Comment: @user2051103 This answer was posted first. Please accept this answer.